# How to inner join in one part and left join on the other

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `Diag` that has these columns in SQL Server:

```
ICD9_L2  RepID
----------------
A         1
D         1
H         1
B         2
D         2
H         2
J         2
A         3
B         3
```

I have another table called `C` that has similar structure different column names:

```
ICD9     n
----------------
A         1
B         1
C         1
D         1
E         1
A         2
B         2
C         2
D         2
```

I want to join both tables considering the following

- I want `C.ICD` to match exactly `Diag.ICD_L2` so if the `Diag.ICD_L2` not in `C.ICD`, then I do not want it returned (i.e. `INNER JOIN`)
- but for `Diag.RepID` even if it does not exist `C.N`, then I want this row to show as `NULL` (i.e `LEFT OUTER JOIN`)

I tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Diag ON C.ICD = Diag.ICD_L2 
                     AND C.N = Diag.RepID
```

but this returns more rows than I want as it included `Diag.ICD_L2` that are not in `C.ICD` too.

I also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM C 
INNER JOIN Diag ON C.ICD = Diag.ICD_L2 
                AND C.N = Diag.RepID
```

That just showed shared rows only.

How can I have a join half of it inner and the other half is left outer?

Comment: You have **far** too much experience to be posting a question in this manner. Your names are confusing - which hinders understanding. Encourage others and reduce the effort need to help by posting a script containing DDL and sample data - something you should know to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the rows from DIAG so just start with DIAG and LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM DIAG
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = DIAG.ICD_L2 AND C.N = DIAG.REPID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FULL OUTER JOIN

```
 SELECT C.IC09, C.n, Diag.RepId
        FROM C 
        FULL OUTER JOIN Diag ON C.ICD = Diag.ICD_L2 
                             AND C.N = Diag.RepID
        WHERE 
        C.ICD IS NOT NULL
```

Or if your db doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN, two queries

1. Select the matches (inner join)
2. Select C rows that don't match (difference)
3. Then union them together

   ```
   SELECT IC09, n, RepID
    FROM C 
    INNER JOIN Diag ON C.ICD = Diag.ICD_L2 
                    AND C.N = Diag.RepID
    UNION
    SELECT IC09, n, null as RepId
    FROM C 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Diag ON C.ICD = Diag.ICD_L2 
                         AND C.N = Diag.RepID
    WHERE 
    Diag.RepID IS NULL
   ```